# Unable to disable lockscreen in 22.04 Jammy via GUI

Tags: lock-screen

Steps taken:

settings -> Screen -> disable everything

[image: settings_screen]

The result:
Lockscreen still appearing as it did prior to these changes.

*The machine was reset several times since then and this issue persists.
**This is a VM running of VBox.

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to eliminate the need to enter your password or select and account when first booting the machine?

Comment: @matigo No, just to make sure the machine never reverts back into the login screen (which I think is called a lockscreen) after the initial login.